# SPSS- how to make the histogram template refer to the y axis as percentage

Tags: templates, histogram, spss

I have an odd issue regarding the SPSS (version 20) use of Chart Template, and any help will be appriciated.

I used the GUI to manualy define a chart template for Histograms. Those are simple definitions:

1) set the x axis between 0 to 100.

2) set the y axis as percent and not as actual number of examples within each bin.

3) set the bin sizes to 5.

4) set the maximal value of the y axis to 20.

I saved the template using the File->Save ChartTemplate  option after changing the definitions of one histogram.

Oddly, when I implement the template on a new histogram, only definitions 1,3,4 are generated while 2 is omitted. I searched for a solution and did not find any. This is extremly frustrating since  I need to waste time and effort to manualy reset the axis to the right definition over any new histogram I make (which is a lot :/ ).

There might be a way to hack the template code using notepad but I did not see any mention of the Y axis there.

Any help and comment would be much appriciated.

Comment: 2 you can set via syntax if you use GGRAPH to generate the histogram.

Comment: Thanks. how would you have done it? I did not see the option to set the y axis as percent and not as actual number of examples within each bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say offhand how to set up a template to do any of those aspects, but here is an example using syntax to specify those four options.

```
SET SEED 10.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 500.
  COMPUTE Var = RV.UNIFORM(0,90).
  END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
DATASET NAME Sim.
FORMATS Var (F3.0).
EXECUTE.


GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Var MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Var=col(source(s), name("Var"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Var"), delta(5))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Percent in Bin"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(1), min(0), max(100))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), max(20))
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.percent.count(bin.rect(Var, binWidth(5)), base.all(acrossPanels()))))
END GPL.
```

And this is what the graph looks like for me (with my default chart template) in V25.

[image: Histogram Example]